# Run bower from root user, it's possible? How?

Tags: node.js, symfony, bower

I have a local development server where I test a lot of things, now I'm playing with bower to manage the libraries' dependencies in my Symfony2 project. After getting NodeJS (v0.10.31) installed and bower (1.3.9), I tried to run the command `sp:bower:install` which belongs to Symfony2 SpBowerBundle from console as `root`:

```
Symfony > sp:bower:install
Installing bower dependencies for "TemplateBundle" into "/var/www/html/tanane/src/Tanane/TemplateBundle/Resources/config/bower/../../public/components"

bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.

http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option
```

I know that adding `--allow-root` works since I tested directly from bash but it apparently isn't allowed from the bundle command line. Now, is the only way to run bower as `root` to add `--allow-root` or does it exist another way ?

Comment: `echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc`

Answer (score 149, accepted):

below answer is for symfony framework's bundle, 
**but if you come here from google** using phrase "**bower root**" you have two options to solve that:

1. add --allow-root to command
2. set global bower config that will allow
   running bower as root

**Option 1:** you can run bower as root by typing:

```
bower install --allow-root
```

root is allowed by setting --allow-root command parameter

**Option 2:** is using global setting that allows root, by creating file:
**/root/.bowerrc**
which have inside following configuration:

```
{ "allow_root": true }
```

---

how to do this in **SpBowerBundle** symfony bundle:
probably you haven't set sp_bower.allow_root to true in SpBowerBundle config

in bundle config, by default you have set something like this:

```
allow_root: false # optional
```

but you should have:

```
allow_root: true
```

so in app/config/config.yml add this bundle config

```
sp_bower:
    allow_root: false # optional
```

bundle config reference (all settings):
https://github.com/Spea/SpBowerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration_reference.md

Comment: where do you put allow_root: true ??

Comment: @Tyvain, I had the same question. I installed Bower on FreeBSD 10 without Symfony. Type: cd / Then ee .bowerrc. Add there: 
{
  "allow_root": true
} See http://bower.io/docs/config/ for more information on .bowerrc file.

Comment: The `allow_root` value has to be set in your `app/config/config.yml`. Just follow the link in the answer.

Comment: Option 2 Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

If you are encountering this issue on Docker containers just add this line in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc
```

Comment: where i have to add in docker file?

Answer (score 17):

I [fixed](http://samwize.com/2015/09/07/fix-npm-slash-bower-install-with-su/) a similar problem by changing the directory permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Answer (score 5):

This might be stupid but for me `bower install --allow-root` did not work but `bower --allow-root install` did, using grunt-bower-install version 1.6.0

This was on a docker running with root user, perhaps will save someone some time :)

Answer (score 3):

Faced similar issue when installing swagger-editor.
Changed the following line in package.json from

```
"bower-install": "bower install"
```

to

```
"bower-install": "bower install --allow-root"
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me **(add -u parameter on docker run)**

`bash
docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/www -w /www -u node node ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install`

Answer (score 2):

For My case it is in Pom.xml where i have added as an argument as below:

```
<executable>bower</executable>
 <arguments>
 <argument>install</argument>
  <argument>--allow-root</argument>
 </arguments>
```

If need to avoid this --allow--root parameter we can do a compile out of root user

Answer (score 0):

remover / delete bower_components
and reinstall bower

```
bower install
```