# Cannot run Bower as Root, where is Bower Configuration file in Debian?

Tags: jquery, node.js, debian, npm, bower

Good afternoon,

I am attempting to run a "bower install" command on an existing project, but I get the error

```
Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.
```

From reading the post below, I understand I need to change the option `allow_root: false` to true

[Run bower from root user, it's possible? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672924/run-bower-from-root-user-its-possible-how)

However, I cannot find the file where I need to change this option!!

Where can I locate this file in Debian7? Or likewise, can I input this option somewhere in the "bower install" command???

I cannot run this as a user, because the project requires root for everything else.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Just add the flag:

`sudo bower install --allow-root`

Answer (score 0):

Create a .bowerrc file in your project, then add the `allow_root: true` option. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25674462/2303429)