# Bower install EACCESS error

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower

Im getting this error trying to install dependencies from bower.json (bower install) and i don't know what is it or how i can fix it... any help would be apreciated.

```
 ✘ deniz946@UbuntuOS  ~/Desktop/meanapp/client   resourcejs  bower install
/home/deniz946/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/deniz946/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:431:33)
    at Object.create.all.get (/home/deniz946/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/home/deniz946/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
    at readCachedConfig (/home/deniz946/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
    at defaultConfig (/home/deniz946/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/deniz946/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
```

Comment: Order it as superuser, `sudo bower install`.

Comment: You should not have to run bower with sudo. You messed up when installing it. There's a folder's permission issue for sure.

Comment: How I can fix that permissions issue?

Comment: @FridoxFL `sudo chown <yourusername> <pathtothefilewithwrongpermissions>`

Comment: @nem i've did that and now im getting this error http://pastebin.com/yaZQy8d7

Comment: @FridoxFL you are getting a permissions issue again. Most likely your permissions problem is somewhere higher up, you might need to recursively `chown` the `.cache` folder as well but perhaps more research on this issue might show you a better way to solve this. Usually these problems arise when you install `npm` or `bower` with `sudo` when it doesn't need it and then anything they use will require `sudo` permissions as well.

Comment: @nem Fixed with chown -r the .cache folder, thanks you very much!

Answer (score 6):

This command should work . It provide permission to bower configration.

> sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm 
>   sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config

and also give permission to folder by

> sudo chmod -R 777 foldername

.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing access permissions error. Use sudo:

```
sudo bower install
```

**EDIT:**
`sudo` does not seem to be working with `bower install`. This works for me though:

```
bower install --allow-root
```

Comment: When I use sudo, I get another kind of error "sudo bower install" 
>>/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: Bower [usually requires the `--allow-root` flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672924/run-bower-from-root-user-its-possible-how)

Comment: The node binary may not be on your $PATH. try symlinking it like so "ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node"

Comment: @Mike Just did it but still not working, getting this error http://pastebin.com/yaZQy8d7

Comment: This will not work in NPM versions > 6. See my answer for why.

Answer (score 1):

For a more exotic take, where you are running as root in Docker and experiencing this, one should know that NPM is running as *the owner of the current working directory*. So in case you are `root` and does not work no matter what you try, try listing the files and see if they are owned by `root`. If not, it will never work, unless you change the ownership to root.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70298239/200987) for the full explanation and references to source code in NPM.