# Apache superset dev mode

Tags: apache-superset

If i run non-dev mode:
`docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up` then everything is fine.
But run in dev mode:
`docker-compose up` - front is not displayed correctly.[image]
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I used the solution given by bhowmik23 on [this issue](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/17076) and it worked for me. I was able to run it successfully on a 64-bit Ubuntu system. I had to install node and npm with apt though; I was using nvm prior and it wasn't working.

Here is the solution I found:

```
I think the problem was solve by following this steps:

Remove Node stage codes from Dockerfile
Remove node_modules from superset-frontend dir if exist
Run cd superset-frontend in cmd
Run npm install&&npm run dev
Run docker-compose up
Hopefully it will be work
```

And here's essentially the commands I ran, from the superset root directory:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
cd ./superset-frontend
sudo rm -rf ./node_modules/*
sudo npm install # you can also run 'npm run dev' but I think that's optional and it won't exit by itself
cd ../ # exit to the root directory
sudo docker compose up # or whatever command you're using to build your docker compose file
```

Answer (score 1):

if you run `docker-compose up` it builds the frontend assets which takes time. Check the logs to follow along on the build progress. If the frontend container is dying early, I recommend increasing the RAM dedicated to Docker to at least 8 GB (especially if you're on Mac OS).

The non-dev.yml one skips building the frontend assets.

Comment: Approximately how long is the build process if you run `docker compose up`?  How do I know it's still running?  And how do I know if it's complete?

Answer (score 0):

When running in **dev mode**, the *superset-node* container needs to finish building assets in order for the UI to render properly.

I managed to fix this by doing the follow after cloning Superset repo:

- `cd superset`
- Install node v16 on my machine (this is the version used by Superset as of writing). I use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) with `.nvmrc` file: `echo "v16.20.2" > .nvmrc`
- `sudo rm -rf superset-frontend/packages/superset-ui-demo/node_modules`
- `sudo chown root.root -R ./superset-frontend`

**NB** The last step is due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298238/getting-eaccess-when-running-npm-8-as-root) with NPM v8 used by Superset.

After this, you can run it in **dev mode** and follow the logs of the *superset-frontend container* only as per below:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker logs -f $(docker ps -q --filter ancestor=node:16)
```