# NPM / Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm

when i type "npm run build:prod"

```
build:prod
    npm run build -- --configuration production --aot --optimization=false
```

i get this error :

```
> fancy-name@0.0.0 build:prod
> npm run build -- --configuration production --aot --optimization=false

glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
 errno: -13,
 code: 'EACCES',
 syscall: 'scandir',
 path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
}
npm WARN logfile Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'
npm WARN logfile  error cleaning log files [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
npm WARN logfile   errno: -13,
npm WARN logfile   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN logfile   syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN logfile   path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
npm WARN logfile }
⸨⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠙ : WARN logfile Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'
> fancy-name@0.0.0 build
> ng build "--configuration" "production" "--aot" "--optimization=false"

Node.js version v17.4.0 detected.file Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0-next || >=13.0.0 <14.0.0,ogs'
but Angular version 12.1.3 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://update.angular.io/
```

i already try to delete node_module & package.json and run `NPM install` again, but it didnt work
(Linux 4.19.0-16-cloud-amd64)

EDIT : solved with `chown -R root /path/of/your/project`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update: this problem and the answer below only applies to NPM 7 and 8 ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70298239/200987)).**

This quickfix should remove the issue by installing an NPM version >= 9.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

---

**Original answer (applies to NPM 7 and 8 shipped with Node 15-19)**

This is understandably a confusing error; you run `npm` as root, and yet it says you do not have access to the files? There is a good reason :) These questions are essentially about the same thing:

- [Getting EACCESS when running NPM 8 as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298238)
- [Bower install EACCESS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032061)

My [quite long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298238/fs-readfilesync-throwing-eaccess-when-called-using-npm-but-not-using-node/70298239#70298239) goes into details on what is happening, but the essence is this:

> (NPM) ... uses this bit of code to determine who to run as:
>
> `const { uid, gid } = isRoot ? inferOwner.sync(cwd) : {}`
>
> and as the docs of infer-owner module says:
> *Infer the owner of a path based on the owner of its nearest existing parent*

So if you are running NPM as root you need to change the owner of the current directory to root as well:

```
chown -R root /path/of/your/project
```

But all this trouble should point you to the real solution: do not run NPM as root. You have no idea what kind of scripts might run as a `postinstall` trigger or similar. Be safe; only use the root account when necessary using `sudo`.

### Addendum: try version 6 or >= 9 of NPM

As mentioned in the linked answer:

> This behavior is only for NPM versions 7 and 8. NPM versions < 7, which are the ones shipped with Node 12-14, work perfectly fine when running as root.

So some quick fixes would be

- `npm install -g npm@latest # Use the latest version of NPM`
- `npm install -g nvm && nvm use 14 # Note: End of Life on May 2023`
- `npm install -g nvm && nvm use 18 # Uses NPM 9, too new for some deps?`

Comment: i already try to change the owner, nothing work :/, maybe i do something wrong, but i dont figure out

Comment: To change the owner to root, you do `chown -R root /path/of/your/project`.

Comment: damm, im doing chown command wrong, the error is no more thanks !

Comment: sadly node 14 is end-of-life next month so, just staying on 14 isnt a very good solution any more...

Comment: @steev Good point. I will update the "try Node 14" bit to reflect that. I already did that in the longer answer I linked to (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70298239/200987). The old behavior is back in NPM 9, so that is the quickest fix :)

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative approach: use a non-root user.

NPM is *trying really hard* (see [other answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70953525/200987)) to not execute anything as root. So what about trying just that - not being root? You would do something like this

1. Add a local user ([AMI guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/)), typically `adduser john.doe --disabled-password`
2. Login as the new user `sudo -s -u john.doe`
3. Clone your repo: `git clone https://github.com/foo/bar; cd bar`
4. Run NPM command `npm i;npm run build:prod`

Comment: no any other way to do it with root ?

Comment: I posted a way to do this as root in my linked answer. I will repost it below

Comment: Why do you have to be root, btw? I have been using Linux for 20 years and never need to be root for anything but occational admin work, if doing it right.

Comment: it's not my server, my "boss" say "do it in root" so ... x)

Comment: haha, if the boss says so, and he is the kind of boss that does not listen to reasonable suggestions, then I totally understand. Thankfully never had to experience that. Good luck!

Answer (score -4):

> glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {

This means it is trying to read something on 'root' directory, something which always needs root access.

Try to run the command like this:

```
sudo npm run build:prod
```

Extra: Usually you should NOT run commands with sudo. If you come from a Windows background think of it as 'Run as administrator', only with even more privileges, so if you are running a malicious script it could have access to almost everything on your system. There are ofc some JS libraries which need root/sudo access to do their things tho

Comment: hi, thanks for reply,
im on Linux 4.19.0-16-cloud-amd64
and im loged as root
running with sudo dont change anything :/

Comment: That won't worK in newer NPM versions

Comment: Can you try to use Node 16? Also `sudo chown -R username:username /root/.npm/_logs` might work if you don't have permissions set correctly

Comment: im on node v17.4.0, i will try node 16,
chown command dont solve the error

Comment: Also found this if this is your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules/59575266#59575266

Comment: same error with node 16
edit: installing node with nvm dont work too

Comment: @sediballiu See my answer for why none of these approaches will ever work. It works on older Node versions that ship with NPM <= v6.