# Change path to default bower.json

Tags: javascript, bower

In the root of application sources `~/MyProjects/angular_training $`
I run:

```
bower install
```

and receive exception:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/my_user/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.
```

Why does it happen so, why it looks for `bower-github.json`? I have my own `.bowerrc` and `bower.json` in the project root.

Comment: You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25674462/639406

Comment: Thank you, @swapnesh ! It was helpful.