# Impossible to run bower install with docker and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, docker, bower

When my DockerFile try to run

```
bower install --allow-root
```

I have these errors in the output:

```
bower malarkey#~1.3.1                     invalid-meta for:/tmp/54d5301ca4ac8eed08df9f9e0be95204/bower/5ad5356aae67f7eb24e62bd78904bec0-10-jLZ9CI/bower.json
bower malarkey#~1.3.1                     invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain minified files
bower malarkey#~1.3.1                         resolved https://github.com/yuanqing/malarkey.git#1.3.3
bower angular-scroll#^1.0.2                   mismatch Version declared in the json (1.0.0) is different than the resolved one (1.0.2)
bower angular-jwt#^0.1.11                     mismatch Version declared in the json (0.1.9) is different than the resolved one (0.1.11)
bower angular-file-upload#^2.5.0          invalid-meta for:/tmp/54d5301ca4ac8eed08df9f9e0be95204/bower/e60440287b4df1cbc04045e77a8c05f5-10-xRC1SU/bower.json
bower angular-file-upload#^2.5.0          invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain minified files
bower angular-google-analytics#^1.1.9     invalid-meta for:/tmp/54d5301ca4ac8eed08df9f9e0be95204/bower/f41b7351bf79de70b7910978744e7bc7-10-Av0m2D/bower.json
bower angular-google-analytics#^1.1.9     invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain minified files
bower jqvmap#^1.5.1                       invalid-meta for:/tmp/54d5301ca4ac8eed08df9f9e0be95204/bower/4c269b1b72f5facccf21d5a6d730ee6e-10-J711uU/bower.json
bower jqvmap#^1.5.1                       invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain minified files
bower jqvmap#^1.5.1                           mismatch Version declared in the json (1.5.0) is different than the resolved one (1.5.1)
bower js-xlsx#^0.12.4                     invalid-meta for:/tmp/54d5301ca4ac8eed08df9f9e0be95204/bower/8d63ef64e2b12f5b0d8616fa7e1b8597-10-w6KAFI/bower.json
bower js-xlsx#^0.12.4                     invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain minified files

bower                                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular-aria
The command '/bin/sh -c bower install --allow-root' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This happened after I installed "angular-scroll" but I can't find a way to fix this problem.
This prevents me to build my dock and update my server.

Comment: Is there typo in first line? I mean is it allow-row OR allow-root ? Also Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672924/run-bower-from-root-user-its-possible-how if it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
bower install --force
```

Try installing forcefully if you have got an unmaintained bower.json